# Textcolor selector not working

Tags: android, textview

I did this before. I copy-pasted. I copy-pasted many other examples from the net. I simply cannot make the textcolor selector work. It sets the default color to the textview, but it won't change if you click on the textview. The settings_selector for the background works fine.

This is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/settings_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/llRecentChanges"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp">
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/llRecentChanges2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAbout"
        android:text="@string/settings_recentchanges"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/settings_selector_txt" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAbout2"
        android:text="@string/settings_recentchanges2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@drawable/settings_selector_txt"
        android:textSize="10dp">
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the settings_selector_txt xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffa800" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffa800" />
    <item android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</selector>
```

or this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:color="#ccc"/>

</selector>
```

or this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
    <item android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

None of them is working. Putting the selector xml to the color folder is also no solution.
Any ideas?

Comment: If these answer are useful accept, if they are not useful comment and say why?

Comment: Look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920859/android-tabs-textcolor-selector-ignores-state-pressed/55904776#55904776

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Make sure your TextView is ready for listening the states you are applying for.
For instance, to be able to reach the "state_pressed" your textView should be clickable:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

EDIT: There we go. This layout does the job. Note that the View that gathers the click event is the linearLayout, but the TextView reproduces it because of "duplicateParentState" set to true. The color selector would take care of the colors for the different states.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/testLlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@drawable/textview_selector"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code for the color selector.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:color="#ccc"/>

</selector>
```

That should be it.

Comment: This is not good. I don't want to click on the textviews, since that means when I click on the upper one, only the upper one's textcolor changes. I need to handle this in the linearlayout,

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. Then you need to inherit the state front the parent in your text views, by putting "android:duplicateParentState="true"" in all the views you need it.

Comment: Although make sure you set your parent layout (your LinearLayout in this case) clickable = true.

Comment: Be more specific please with a code. Adding android:duplicateParentState="true" to the TextView and adding android:textColor="@drawable/settings_selector_txt" to the linearlayout around the textview does nothing

Comment: You don't need to add a color selector to the LinearLayout. 
The idea is that the textview will take the state of his parent (LinearLayout in this case). That's why we need to add the duplicateParentState to the textview. The state we want to reach and for which we have a selector is the pressed state. And we just want our TextView to reach this state so that the only View which needs the selector is that one. (our TextView)
Nothing else is needed. If you still need more help I'd give you some code. But is better to guess it ;)

Comment: I really have no idea what I should do to make this work. Please help with a code

Comment: I am going to try this out in 24 hrs, i was on holiday

Comment: Thank you. I thought I did the same but somehow it must have been different.

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that in these selectors, you can't use referenced colors (at least as of API 19).  These have to be hexadecimal numbers starting with #.  It took me a while to notice via an Eclipse tooltip that the android:color must be hex.

Answer (score 29):

No need to set `android:clickable="true"` to TextView or `android:duplicateParentState="true"`.

**Solution**

Step-1: Define your color selector under **res/color** folder(Jose L Ugia's color selector is good for this.) 

Step-2: set this color selector to your TextView as `android:textColor="@color/m_text_selector"` (not as @drawable/*!!!)

**Note:** If you want to set textColor selector programmatically, you must get your selector as color state list not as a color;

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.m_text_selector));
```

That's all.

Comment: I was using -> item android:drawable="@color/white" but it should be item android:color="@color/white" in selector...thanks @Devrim

Answer (score 2):

I think using ColorStateList best choice to older and latest versions of Android.

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}, // pressed
    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused}, // focused
    new int[] {}
};
int[] colors = new int[] {
    getResources().getColor(R.color.green_color), // green
    getResources().getColor(R.color.green_color), // green
    getResources().getColor(R.color.white)  // white
};
ColorStateList list = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
mTextView.setFocusable(true);
mTextView.setClickable(true);
mTextView.setTextColor(list);
```

Comment: How about having multiple states set to true? e.g. `focused` and `selected` are 2 states so we have 4 combinations. How is the order determined for the array?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all layouts that may be wrapping your TextViews before your "clickable" layout also have duplicateParentState="true", otherwise, the text view won't reach the element state you want.

Answer (score 0):

You must set this in your code : `android:clickable="true"` for TextViews