# Android tabs textcolor selector ignores state_pressed

Tags: android, android-styles, textcolor

I have created my own android theme to change the look of the actionbar tabs. The problem is that textcolor selector seems to ignore state_pressed attribute, so the color of tab text is always the same, even if this tab is pressed. There is no problem with other states, for example state_selected is correctly recognized and selected tab has text color, which is different from unselected tabs text color.

What is more, i have also created selector for tabs background and it works fine with state_pressed (if the tab is pressed, it's backround color is changed).

There are some pieces of my code:

styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Theme.MyTheme.TabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyTheme.TabTextStyle</item>
</style>

...

<style name="Theme.MyTheme.TabStyle"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_selector</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyTheme.TabTextStyle"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textcolor_selector</item>
</style>
```

background_selector.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00ff00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#0000ff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffff00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

textcolor_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false"
          android:color="#ff0000"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#0000ff"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false"
          android:color="#ffff00"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#00ff00"/>
</selector>
```

I have tried everything without success - state_pressed attribute seems to be ignored, but only in textcolor_selector. Please, help me understand and solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Review the [Customize the Text Color](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText) section of the ActionBar Styling documentation - it mentions that `Note: The custom style applied to titleTextStyle should use TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title as the parent style.` - perhaps a change there might help correct the problem.

Another place to look would be [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style) under the `Example theme` section - it shows an example of `android:actionBarTabTextStyle` that might help get things sorted for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I've already seen both links you posted and they were not helpful.

**Ad1.** This note is about titletextstyle, not tabtextstyle. My parent hierarchy for tabtextstyle is ok.

**Ad2.** This example doesn't even use selector for text color and it uses specific hierarchy to support devices with android < 3.0.

I use hierarchy from this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText) , section "For Android 3.0 and higher only".

Comment: Just to be sure - your textcolor_selector file is located within the `res/color/` directory?  As noted in your statement `<item name="android:textColor">@color/textcolor_selector</item>`

Comment: Might not make a difference, but in all the examples that I've seen in the android documentation `state_pressed` is [used first](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) before other options and is listed first [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) also --- try to change the order of `states` in your textcolor_selector file, putting `state_pressed` before the `state_selected` for each `<item>`

Comment: Yes, my textcolor_selector file is located within res/color/. I've also tried with @drawble/textcolor_selector and drawable directory, still nothing. The order of the attributes shouldn't matter, however I've already tried to put state_pressed at the very beginning without success, I've tried even with something like that:
`<selector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">; <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff0000" /> <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#0000ff"/>
</selector>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the drawable folder:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/color_700" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/color_100" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/bloqueado" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```