# android:textColor not working for TextView

Tags: android, textview, textcolor

`android:textColor` doesn't seem to work for `TextView` inside a nested `LinearLayout`. I had a look at the question at [Textcolor selector not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080995/textcolor-selector-not-working). But it is also not working in my case. Following is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CreateActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:hint="Title:"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lblTitleEdit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter your title here"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:inputType="text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblVenue"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:hint="Venue:"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lblVenueEdit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter your venue here"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:inputType="text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Am I making any mistake here?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use android:text="Title:" instead of  android:hint="Title:"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textcolor selector not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080995/textcolor-selector-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I already had a look a the question and it was not working for me. So, while posting the question I have added it in the description that the solution didn't work me. Anyways, I found out my mistake. I was using `android:hint` instead of `android:text`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used hint as text here. So you have to apply color to your hint with the following code. or you can also change hint to text in your `xml`.

```
android:textColorHint="#000"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add android: text, you give hint property and try to text color change

> android:text="Title:"

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CreateActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:text="Title:"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lblTitleEdit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter your title here"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:inputType="text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblVenue"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:text="Venue:"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lblVenueEdit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter your venue here"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:inputType="text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

For `android:text="Title:"` you should use `android:textColor="#000000"`

And

For `android:hint="Title:"` you should use `android:textColorHint="#000000"`

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to give text color to `android: hint` and replace it with `android: text`.

See the answer below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CreateActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:text="Title:"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lblTitleEdit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter your title here"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:inputType="text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblVenue"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:text="Venue:"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lblVenueEdit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:hint="Enter your venue here"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:inputType="text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here what you set in text view is hint text. So , you need to set `textColorHint` property of text-view.

> What you was doing is setting color on text . Which will not work because you haven't entered any text in text-view .

```
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:hint="Title:"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, you wrote hint in a Textview so for the apply color in hint use like,

```
android:textColorHint="#000000"
```

Or if you want to use text color then you have to set text into your Textview as below:

```
android:text="Title:"
android:textColor="#000000"
```

If you are using a hint in a TextView then use as below:

```
android:hint="Title:"
android:textColorHint="#000000"
```